# Select first row of first table and last row with same class in second table using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have two tables like shown below with same class.
My requirement is to select first row of first table and last row of second table using CSS.

```html
<table class='mx-table'>
 <tr class="mx-active-week">
 <tr class="mx-active-week">
</table>
<table class='mx-table'>
 <tr class="mx-active-week">
 <tr class="mx-active-week">
</table>
```

I have tried like `.mx-active-week:nth-child(1)` but it is giving me first row of second table.
I don't want to use table class `.mx-table:nth-child(1)` `.mx-active-week:nth-child(1)` to fetch the first row of first table.

Is it possible to use only `mx-active-week` for this?

Please help.

Thanks,
Jyoti

Comment: why I don't want to use table class '.mx-table:nth-child(1) .mx-active-week:nth-child(1) ?

Comment: Hi.. I just want to have first row and last row with css mx-active-week. It could be the case that it don't even exist in first table, then I need to select rows from second table.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use `:nth-child`, you could utilize other pseudo classes like [`:first-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type) and [`:last-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type) to select the first and last `<table>` elements. Then use [`:first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child) to target the first tables `<tr>` and [`:last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child) to target the last `<tr>` of the second table.

Using `:first-of-type` selects the first element among of a group of sibling elements, where `:last-of-type` selects the last element among a group of sibling elements. In this example, the two `<table>`'s are sibling elements.

```css
/* can remove this table styling, used for better visual */
table {
  margin: .5rem 0;
  border: .1rem solid #333;
}

.mx-table:first-of-type .mx-active-week:first-child {
  color: #f06;
}

.mx-table:last-of-type .mx-active-week:last-child {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<table class='mx-table'>
 <tr class="mx-active-week">
  <td>First row of first table</td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="mx-active-week">
  <td>Last row</td>
 </tr>
</table>
<table class='mx-table'>
 <tr class="mx-active-week">
  <td>First row</td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="mx-active-week">
  <td>Last row of second table</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

If you would like to only use `.mx-active-week` to select the first or last row. You could just use `.mx-active-week:first-of-type` or `.mx-active-week:last-of-type`. Using `:first-child` and `:last-child` would also work in the same fashion selecting the first and last elements among a group of sibling `<tr>` elements. Like you mentioned in the comments, it could be the case that the `.mx-active-week` class didn't exist in the first table so I have shown that below.

```css
/* can remove this table styling, used for better visual */
table {
  margin: .5rem 0;
  border: .1rem solid #333;
}

.mx-active-week:first-of-type {
  color: #f06;
}

.mx-active-week:last-of-type {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<table class='mx-table'>
 <tr>
  <td>First row of first table</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Last row</td>
 </tr>
</table>
<table class='mx-table'>
 <tr class="mx-active-week">
  <td>First row</td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="mx-active-week">
  <td>Second row</td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="mx-active-week">
  <td>Last row of second table</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @Jyoti Let me know if this helps solve your problem!

Comment: thanks for answering.. but i dont want to use mx-table... in my case I only want to use mx-active-week as it could be the case mx-active-week don't exist in first table mx-table or mx-active-week don't exist in second table.

Comment: Your welcome. Hmm okay, let me tinker with a few things and I'll update or remove my answer. Thanks for clarifying. Is it always going to be the first or second row you want to select from the first or second table?

Comment: Hi.. i just want to have first row and last row with css mx-active-week. It could be the case that it don't even exist in first table, then I need to select rows from second table.

Comment: @Jyoti I updated my answer. Have a look at the second part, that should do what you seek by only using the .mx-active-week selector to select the first or last row in the table. Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

simply use as selector for the first `<tr>` of the first `<table>`: `.mx-table:nth-child(1) tr:first-child` and for the second table, last row: `.mx-table:nth-child(2) tr:last-child`

```css
.mx-table:nth-child(1) tr:first-child,
.mx-table:nth-child(2) tr:last-child {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table class='mx-table'>
  <tr class="mx-active-week"><td>Row 1</td></tr>
  <tr class="mx-active-week"><td>Row 2</td></tr>
</table>
<table class='mx-table'>
  <tr class="mx-active-week"><td>Row 3</td></tr>
  <tr class="mx-active-week"><td>Row 4</td></tr>
</table>
```